# Timer adds a certain TableRow multiple times

Tags: java, android, runnable

I have a basic **Timer** in my app:

```
TextView timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
long startTime = 0;

Handler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {                
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000) * 1;
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;                

        timerTextView.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);

        if (minutes == 45 && seconds == 0) {
            addHeader("2nd Half");                   
        }  
    }             
};
```

**addHeader() method:**

```
private void addHeader(String header) {
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTable);    
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(...);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(..);
    textView.setText(header);

    // more code

    tr.addView(textView);
    table.addView(tr);
}
```

**onCreate():**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startTimer();
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
}
```

When my timer reaches 45:00 a new row is added to my TableLayout multiple times. I've created an alternative solution but I'd like to know what I'm missing.

```
if (!isAdded) {
    addHeader("2nd Half");
    isAdded = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to check what is going on is to log every time the `Handler` is run and every time `addHeader` fires

e.g:

```
    Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000) * 1;
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;  
        millis = millis % 1000;              

        timerTextView.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
        Log.d("MainActivity", String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"Checking time: %02d:%02d:%03d" , minutes, seconds, millis));
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);

        if (minutes == 45 && seconds == 0) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"2nd Half: %02d:%02d:%03d" , minutes, seconds, millis));
            addHeader("2nd Half");                   
        }  
    }
```

Doing this you will see that `addHeader` is called twice. This is because  every `500ms` your `Handler` is running, checking the difference between the current time and start time, in minutes and seconds (ignoring ms). To fix the issue try changing

`timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);`

to

`timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);`

Comment: Thanks a lot Isaac!